# OpenCV+Eclipse+Android: Error org.opencv.video Video.java

Tags: java, android, opencv, video

I have been installing OpenCV ([this is the tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package.html)), I read the tutorial but this error appeared (error in Video.java (PHOTO)). I have installed the last version.
I don't understand. Anybody can help me and explain me what happened?
thanks

[image: ERROR]
[image: ERROR2]

Comment: good style - to lay out a mistake with tabs Markers Eclipse IDE's

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If someone have this problem, do this:

In OpenCV **project.properties** change  `target=android-11` (or in some cases 14) to `target=android-17`.

**Edit:** For the newer `OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk` you will need to change it to `target=android-20`.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks. (Also don't forget to accept your answer as well)

Comment: I had the same problem with `OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk`, and I needed `target=android-20`

Answer (score 1):

In each OpenCV project.properties we need to set Android -> Project Build Target -> in my case I use check the toggle Android 4.1.2. but you can choose this android version. Doing that all projects compiled well.

Comment: Can you explain why? [Fuller explanations are better.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)