# OpenCV4Android Samples: Missing .so files

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv, import

I imported all the OpenCV samples for android in Eclipse. I have the right path for NDKROOT. I'm under Ubuntu so I removed the ".cmd" in Build Command. My problem now is that I have errors in the cpp files.

Here is what the CDT Global Build Console says:

```
19:04:34 **** Build of configuration Default for project OpenCV Tutorial 2 - Mixed Processing ****
/home/crash-id/Development/SDK/android-ndk-r10c/ndk-build 
Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:mixed_sample: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lopencv_java    
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    
Android NDK:     current module    
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : libmixed_sample.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libmixed_sample.so

19:04:34 Build Finished (took 299ms)

19:04:37 **** Build of configuration Default for project OpenCV Sample - face-detection ****
/home/crash-id/Development/SDK/android-ndk-r10c/ndk-build all 
Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:detection_based_tracker: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lopencv_java    
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    
Android NDK:     current module    
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : libdetection_based_tracker.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libdetection_based_tracker.so

19:04:37 Build Finished (took 171ms)

19:04:37 **** Build of configuration Default for project OpenCV Sample - native-activity ****
/home/crash-id/Development/SDK/android-ndk-r10c/ndk-build 
Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:native_activity: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lopencv_java    
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    
Android NDK:     current module    
[armeabi-v7a] Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.6] libs/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver
[armeabi-v7a] Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : libnative_activity.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libnative_activity.so

19:04:38 Build Finished (took 343ms)

19:04:59 **** Auto Build of configuration Default for project OpenCV Sample - face-detection ****
/home/crash-id/Development/SDK/android-ndk-r10c/ndk-build all 
Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:detection_based_tracker: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lopencv_java    
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    
Android NDK:     current module    
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : libdetection_based_tracker.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libdetection_based_tracker.so

19:05:00 Build Finished (took 229ms)

19:05:00 **** Auto Build of configuration Default for project OpenCV Sample - face-detection ****
/home/crash-id/Development/SDK/android-ndk-r10c/ndk-build all 
Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:detection_based_tracker: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lopencv_java    
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    
Android NDK:     current module    
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : libdetection_based_tracker.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libdetection_based_tracker.so

19:05:01 Build Finished (took 404ms)

19:05:01 **** Auto Build of configuration Default for project OpenCV Sample - native-activity ****
/home/crash-id/Development/SDK/android-ndk-r10c/ndk-build 
Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:native_activity: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lopencv_java    
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    
Android NDK:     current module    
[armeabi-v7a] Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.6] libs/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver
[armeabi-v7a] Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : libnative_activity.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libnative_activity.so

19:05:02 Build Finished (took 229ms)

19:05:02 **** Auto Build of configuration Default for project OpenCV Tutorial 2 - Mixed Processing ****
/home/crash-id/Development/SDK/android-ndk-r10c/ndk-build 
Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:mixed_sample: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lopencv_java    
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    
Android NDK:     current module    
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : libmixed_sample.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libmixed_sample.so

19:05:02 Build Finished (took 233ms)

19:05:32 **** Auto Build of configuration Default for project OpenCV Sample - face-detection ****
/home/crash-id/Development/SDK/android-ndk-r10c/ndk-build all 
Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:detection_based_tracker: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lopencv_java    
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    
Android NDK:     current module    
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : libdetection_based_tracker.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libdetection_based_tracker.so

19:05:32 Build Finished (took 119ms)

19:05:32 **** Auto Build of configuration Default for project OpenCV Sample - native-activity ****
/home/crash-id/Development/SDK/android-ndk-r10c/ndk-build 
Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:native_activity: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lopencv_java    
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    
Android NDK:     current module    
[armeabi-v7a] Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.6] libs/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver
[armeabi-v7a] Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : libnative_activity.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libnative_activity.so

19:05:33 Build Finished (took 185ms)

19:05:33 **** Auto Build of configuration Default for project OpenCV Tutorial 2 - Mixed Processing ****
/home/crash-id/Development/SDK/android-ndk-r10c/ndk-build 
Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:mixed_sample: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lopencv_java    
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    
Android NDK:     current module    
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : libmixed_sample.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libmixed_sample.so

19:05:33 Build Finished (took 122ms)
```

When I open OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk/sdk/native/libs/armeabi-v7a I can see that these .so files aren't really there. What should I do? I need to fix it ASAP (it's for school project).

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenCV+Eclipse+Android: Error org.opencv.video Video.java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18727199/opencveclipseandroid-error-org-opencv-video-video-java)